# Exposing Kubernetes container IP outside its namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with two namespaces, `dbns` (where a database lives) and `jobland` (where jobs run from).

I would like to run a `Job` from a container running in the `jobland` namespace that will connect to and run scripts against a DB living in the `dbns` namespace.

When I run `get pod,statefulset,svc,configmap -o wide` I see that my DB has an IP of `10.1.0.34`, but I'm assuming thats only "reachable" from other containers running inside the `dbns` namespace, correct? If so, how could I expose its IP so that items from outside the `dbns` namespace can connect to it (such as something running in `jobland`)?

Comment: Unless there are NetworkPolicy-Resources preventing it, this should work by default. Kuberentes is not secure-by-default, so communication between containers is not namespace-restricted. Meaning: You should be able to simply reach the pod by its IP from all namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exposing your objects (pods, deployments, etc) using a K8S service you can expose them outside namespaces with an IP or with FQDN

Here is an example of how to do it:
https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/05-Services#0403-using-the-full-DNS-name

---

- As a best practice you should not rely on the Cluster IP since it can change and will "break" your connectivity.
- The recommended way is as mentioned above to use the FDDN which is automatically created for you once you add the `Service` object to your namespace and resource.

[image]

The name (FQDN) will be the same regardless of the IP and cluster which your code are deployed to.

You can verify this name, for example:
[image]